# Tabs data is not loading dynamic Data in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi I am very new to Ionic, I am implementing the Ionic App using Tabs. In my app has three tabs, each contains each component and bring dynamic data (Rest API call).

But only first time it has getting data next time clicking on tab data is not updating (Rest API call is not calling) because I wrote into `ngOninIt()` Method.

below is my code:

**tabs.html code :**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="Home" icon="home" href="/tabs/(home:home)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="About" icon="information-circle" href="/tabs/(about:about)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="about"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Contact" icon="contacts" href="/tabs/(contact:contact)">
    <ion-router-outlet name="contact"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.routing.ts**

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPageComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'mustang',
            outlet: 'tab1',
            loadChildren: './mustang/mustang.module#MustangModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'camaro',
            outlet: 'tab2',
            loadChildren: './camaro/camaro.module#CamaroModule'
          },
          {
            path: 'charger',
            outlet: 'tab3',
            loadChildren: './charger/charger.module#ChargerModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/lazy-load-tabs/tabs/(tab1:mustang)'
      }
    ]

;
```

**home.module.ts**

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: HomePage }])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    alert("app home tabs is clickced...");
  }
}
```

But above alert method calling only once, where can I write the code it should call every time click on tab.

Thanks in advance !!!!!

Comment: @fateme fazli  any help from your side, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use another lifecycle events which is called every time like `ionViewWillEnter`

For more details, see
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Comment: Even `ionViewWillEnter` is also not calling everytime, it is calling only once. becuase we are using different outlets

Comment: So, is this the answer then? It has been marked as the correct answer with a broken link and a comment from the OP about it not working...